# CSS first-of-type of that parent, but not further descendents

Tags: css, less

https://codepen.io/bazzle/pen/jyWdjM

I want to select the first `p` but not the `p` nested inside blockquote, or any other element.

In other words the first `p` out of all the child `p`'s but not grandchild `p`'s

```
<div class="article__body">
  <p>
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
</p>
<blockquote>
  <p>
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  </p>
</blockquote>
<p>
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
</p>
</div>
```

CSS (less)

```
.article__body{
        p:first-of-type{
            background-color:green;
        }
}
```

Comment: Use the `>` combinator. You should seriously consider searching before asking.

Comment: @Harry yes, exactly.

Comment: `.article__body > p:first-child {}` ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWMGXx

Comment: @Banzay: `:first-of-type` is better just in case the outer `p` is not the first child.

Comment: trust me I did, but it's hard to search for something you don't know about yet. thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
.article_body p:nth-of-type(1){
    background-color:green;
}
```

or just create a class
HTLM: `<p class="yourclass"></p>`

CSS: `.yourclass{background-color:green;}`

Answer (score 0):

I try

```
.article__body p:nth-of-type(1){
            background-color:green;
        }
```